# Cross-platform free vector editor for shutterstock contributors

Tags: vector-graphics

Shutterstock has very strict submission requirements for vectors that make it hard to use free software, for example, "no bitmaps" - saving gradients in Inkscape, for example, results in the bitmap problem. ([Reference](http://www.shutterstock.com/buzz/vectors/new-upgraded-vector-submission-requirements))

My ideal tool would be free (e.g. Not Illustrator) or low cost, and available on Mac, Linux, and windows if possible, although Android /iOS tablets seems reasonable too if it has standard vector features.

**In other words:** I am looking for a free (or not-so-expensive) alternative to Adobe Illustrator, which is able to export real vectors in a format that is compatible with Adobe Illustrator 10… including vector gradients-fills and co. Please note that Inkscape is not a valid alternative as it does not support the correct export of gradients-fills. Instead, Inkscape works around the problem by embedding a bitmap of the gradient, which is what I need to prevent to be able to upload my vector files to Shutterstock.

Comment: I have no experience with these kind of things, but you might find this website useful: http://www.labri.fr/perso/barla/blog/?page_id=251 - apparently it has tools coded by a researcher in vector graphics and the Patate Library seems to include a vector gradient tool

Comment: Given all the features the Inkscape has the practical way would be helping with adding vectorized export of gradients to Inkscape.

Comment: Try using interpolate ( http://www.inkscape.org/doc/interpolate/tutorial-interpolate.en.html ) feature of Inkscape to create vector-gradients. I'll make it an answer if it suits your needs.

Answer (score 5):

Google provides [SVG-edit](https://svg-edit.github.io/svgedit/releases/svg-edit-2.8.1/svg-editor.html) which can be used online from just about any platform.

- Free
- Cross Platform
- You can get pure SVG without bitmaps, (unless you add them yourself), even gradients:

e.g.
[Rect with Gradient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHpzT.png)

```
<svg width="640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">!
<!-- Created with SVG-edit - http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/ -->
 <defs>
  <radialGradient id="svg_2" spreadMethod="pad">
   <stop stop-color="#FF0000" offset="0"/>
   <stop stop-color="#00ffff" offset="1"/>
  </radialGradient>
  <radialGradient spreadMethod="pad" id="svg_3">
   <stop offset="0" stop-color="#FF0000"/>
   <stop offset="1" stop-color="#00ffff"/>
  </radialGradient>
 </defs>
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <rect fill="url(#svg_2)" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="5" x="159" y="93" width="251" height="112" id="svg_1"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks! This saved my butt on a project!